# counter is not getting decreased every second using .animate() function using step option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to animate something in 90 seconds

I used the `.animate()`  function and the step option in that.

It comes to 0 when 0 seconds are left but the number is not getting decremented every second !!

Refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/bz8rC/3/)

```
function timeRunner() {
    $("#TimeIndicator").animate({
        width: "0px"
    }, {
        duration: 90000,
        step: function (now) {
            var percent = (Math.round(now) / 136) * 100;
            var timeleft = (percent) * (0.9);

            $("#TimeIndicator").html(Math.round(timeleft));

        },
        complete: function () {
            timerReset();
        }
    })
};

function timerReset() {
    $("#TimeIndicator").animate({
        width: "136px"
    }, 0, function () {
        timeRunner();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the default setting for the animation's [easing](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#easing) is `swing`. Set it to `linear`

Comment: so what should i change it to, to get the counter decrease every second?!
Can you please update the fiddle which would be very helpful

Comment: here is the fiddle link just in case you have missed it out in the question
http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/bz8rC/3/

Comment: I saw it, thought you could figure out how to add the option since you figured out how to do it for the others like duration. Set `easing` to `linear`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/bz8rC/13/
I have changed it to linear 
I think sometimes its decreasing faster like two decrements at a time

Comment: Thanks @epascarello I have upvoted!!
The counter is nearly accurate !!

Answer (score 1):

i have made some changes to the `width: 120px` for demo purpose

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/bz8rC/12/)

```
$('#TimeIndicator').text('12')


var t = setInterval(function () {

if (!parseInt($('#TimeIndicator').width(), 10) == 0) timeRunner();
else {
    $('#TimeIndicator').text('')
    window.clearInterval(t)
}

}, 1000);


function timeRunner() {

$('#TimeIndicator').animate({
    width: '-=10px'
}, function () {
    $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text(), 10) - 1)
})
};
```

**EDIT** for `-1px per second`  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/bz8rC/14/)

```
$('#TimeIndicator').text('120')


var t = setInterval(function () {

if (!parseInt($('#TimeIndicator').width(), 10) == 0) 
{
    timeRunner();

    setTimeout(function(){
               $('#TimeIndicator').text(parseInt($('#TimeIndicator').text(), 10) - 1)
              },100)   
}
else {
    $('#TimeIndicator').text('')
    window.clearInterval(t)
}

}, 1000);




function timeRunner() {

$('#TimeIndicator').animate({
    width: '-=1px'
},'linear')
};
```